# Does the water created by the Tsunami spell disappear after the spell is over?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The [*Tsunami*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tsunami) spell creates quite the amount of water, up to millions of cubic feet. After the spell ends, where does the water go?

Some possibilities:

- It magically disappears just as it came.
- It lingers around, doing what water does.

Answer (score 7):

#### The water lasts for the duration, and disappears afterwards.

The [*Tsunami*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tsunami) spell text says (emphasis mine):

> A wall of water springs into existence at a point you choose within range. You can make the wall up to 300 feet long, 300 feet high, and 50 feet thick. **The wall lasts for the duration.**

Nowhere it states the the water keep on existing after the spell ended. Starting at 300 ft of height, the wall reduces by 50 ft per round, at the end of the 6th one it disappears, per description:

> When the wall reaches 0 ft of height, the spell ends.

For comparison, one can see the spell [*Create or Destroy Water*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-or-destroy-water), which is instantaneous and creates 10 gallons of water that pour into existence for any use:

> **Create Water.** You create up to 10 gallons of clean water within range in an open container.

The spell [*Create Food and Water*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-food-and-water) has a similar effect.